# Flutter Widget Key Checking for Evaluation

Tags: flutter

In one my page, I am using the below code to set a unique key, so that I can verify if it's the page that I need in a different page.

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{
   LoginPage() : super(key: Key("login"));

   ....
}
```

In main page which can have any other page, I want to add a condition to check which is the actual page being displayed.

For the same, I am checking as below.. But this does not evaluate to true.

How should I modify my condition to check for the key name?

```
if (widget.key == Key("login")) { }
```

Below is the full code.

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: SilkThreadApp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {

        if (widget.key == Key("login")) {
          return widget;
        }

        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            child: widget,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0, right: 0.0),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't see any reason why it doesn't evaluate to true, except if `widget.key` is not what you think it is. Can you post your main page code ?

Comment: Added the full code

Comment: That's not the purpose of keys. It's a pretty bad idea

Comment: @RémiRousselet I am sure this is a bad idea. But I don't have any other better idea to check for the page type.. Please let me know your thoughts on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using keys correctly. Keys are used by flutter to detect what needs to be rendered and when. There are multiple types of keys and you should read about them. For your question, there is a rather simple way to do this, inheritance.

```
class BaseStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget{
    final String widgetType;
    const BaseStatelessWidget({this.widgetType});
}

class LoginPage extends BaseStatelessWidget {
    LoginPage() : BaseStatelessWidget(widgetType:"Login"){
         // You actual constructor code here.
    }
}
```

All your stateless widgets can extends to this stateless widget for the `widgetType`. You can use `@required` on `widgetType` too, so flutter gives you an error if one widget is written without the `widgetType`.

The above example assumes you have multiple widgets that you need to know the "page" type for. If it's only this widget, then you don't even need inheritance. Just set a required field to `LoginPage` constructor.

Honestly, you shouldn't need to this kind of page checking, if your state is written correctly. It's a reactive system.

Comment: By this approach, I am forced to extent BaseStatlessWidget in all my widgets. Alshou shouldn't we cast the "widget" to Base widget for verification?

Comment: See you shouldn't have to check for such things if your state is maintained right. But if you have to, and there are multiple different kinds of widgets, then this method works fine. Since all it's doing is adding an extra key layer. You can also try to create a mixin (read interface). Read this for an example: https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3

Comment: If you can explain with some code, it would be useful.